# Laravel , geeting comma separated values as ID for another model

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

so i have this input from invoice_table, "order_numbers",  with values something like this : 91,92,93

in controller :

$invoice->order_numbers = Input::get('order_numbers');

What i need is to find that order numbers ( 91,92,93 ) in orders_table and updated it's value

This is what i try in controller :

```
$invoice->order_numbers = Input::get('order_numbers');
$orderIds = explode(',', $invoice->order_numbers);
    $cnt = count($orderIds);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++) {
        $order = Order::findOrFail($orderIds);
        $order->is_billed = '1';

        $order->save();

    }
```

but i got this error :
BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method save does not exist.

Can somebody help me what to do ? Thanks

Comment: Does your Model class `extends Model`?

Comment: Just redesign your database structure as a properly normalized database

Comment: Rifki you cant use array as param in findOrFail function!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change all your code to:

```
$orderIds = explode(',', request('order_numbers'));
Order::whereIn('id', $ordersIds)->update(['is_billed' => 1]);
```

Your code will generate N * 2 queries (200 queries for 100 IDs) and this code will generate just one query for any number of IDs.

`update()` method uses [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment), so make sure `is_billed` is in `$fillable` array.

Comment: thank you so much Alexey Mezenin. that is so simple and worked. thanks